# How convert list of items into empty vectors in R?

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
list = c('banana', 'apple', 'orange')
```

I want  each list item to become a empty vector, i.e., `""`

Like this:

```
banana
apple
orange
```

Does anyone know how to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `assign`

```
for(nm in list) assign(nm, "")
```

-checking

```
> banana
[1] ""
> apple
[1] ""
> orange
[1] ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You may convert the vector to a named list and use `list2env`.

```
list2env(as.list(setNames(rep('', length(list)), list)), .GlobalEnv)

banana
#[1] ""
apple
#[1] ""
orange
#[1] ""
```

Comment: Or we can use `setNames(rep(list(""), length(lst)), lst)`

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this as well

```
list2env(mapply(setNames, list(list("")), lst), .GlobalEnv)
```

and you will see

```
> banana
[1] ""
> apple 
[1] ""
> orange
[1] ""
```